# How can I show my observable list entries correctly in my WPF view?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I wrote a program which reads XML-data and stores this data in an observable list. Now I have two observable lists of string arrays and I want to show these two different arrays in a listview with two columns.

This is my xaml:

```
<views:MvxWpfView
    x:Class="Ui.MVVMMaPa.Views.HomeView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Ui.MVVMMaPa.Views" xmlns:core="clr-namespace:Ui.MVVMMaPa.Core" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=core:HomeViewModel}"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Text,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <Button Content="Browse" Command="{Binding BrowseCommand}" />
            
            <ListBox Name="ListBox">
                <TextBlock Name="TextBlockName" Text="{Binding ShortNameStringObservableList}" />
                <TextBlock Name="TextBlockid" Text="{Binding ValueStringObservableList}"/>
            </ListBox>
            
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</views:MvxWpfView>
```

My ViewModel:

```
using Logic.MVVMMaPa.ListCreater;
using MvvmCross.Commands;
using MvvmCross.ViewModels;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Ui.MVVMMaPa.Core
{
    public class HomeViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
        public DirectoryIterator directoryIterator = new DirectoryIterator();
        private List<MachineparameterClass> machineparameterList = new List<MachineparameterClass>();
        public IMvxCommand BrowseCommand => new MvxCommand(Browse);

        private ObservableCollection<string[]> shortNameStringObservableList = new ObservableCollection<string[]>();
        public ObservableCollection<string[]> ShortNameStringObservableList
        {
            get { return shortNameStringObservableList; }
            set
            {
                shortNameStringObservableList = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => nameof(ShortNameStringObservableList));
            }

        }
        private ObservableCollection<string[]> valueStringObservableList = new ObservableCollection<string[]>();

        public ObservableCollection<string[]> ValueStringObservableList
        {
            get => valueStringObservableList;
            set
            {
                valueStringObservableList = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => nameof(ValueStringObservableList));
            }
        }
        private void Browse()
        {

            Comparer comparer = new Comparer(directoryIterator.FileIterationOne(directoryIterator.DirectoryIteratorFunction()));
            machineparameterList = comparer.ListComparer();

            for (int i = 0; i < machineparameterList.Count; i++)
            {
                ShortNameStringObservableList.Add(machineparameterList[i].getShortNames());
                ValueStringObservableList.Add(machineparameterList[i].getValues());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my model:

```
using System.ComponentModel;


namespace Logic.MVVMMaPa.ListCreater
{
    public class MachineparameterClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string pluginName;
        string pluginInstanceName;
        string[] shortNames;
        string[] values;
        string[] typesInInt;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
        void OnPropertyChanged(string name) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        public string PluginName
        {
            get { return pluginName; }
            set { pluginName = value; }
        }
        public string PluginInstanceName
        {
            get { return pluginInstanceName; }
            set { pluginInstanceName = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PluginInstanceName)); }
        }
        public string[] ShortNames
        {
            get { return shortNames; }
            set { shortNames = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ShortNames)); }
        }
        public string[] Values
        {
            get { return values; }
            set { values = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Values)); }
        }
        public string[] TypesInInt
        {
            get { return typesInInt; }
            set { typesInInt = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TypesInInt)); }
        }


        public MachineparameterClass()
        {
        }

        public MachineparameterClass(MachineparameterClass machineparameterClass)
        {
            this.pluginName = pluginName;
            this.pluginInstanceName = pluginInstanceName;
            this.shortNames = shortNames;
            this.values = values;
            this.typesInInt = typesInInt;

        }
        public void SetProperty(string prop, string val)
        {

        }
        public MachineparameterClass(string pluginName, string pluginInstanceName, string[] shortNames, string[] values, string[] typesInInt) : base()
        {
            this.pluginName = pluginName;
            this.pluginInstanceName = pluginInstanceName;
            this.shortNames = shortNames;
            this.values = values;
            this.typesInInt = typesInInt;
        }

        public String getPluginName() { return this.PluginName; }
        public String getPluginInstanceName() { return this.PluginInstanceName; }
        public String[] getShortNames() { return this.ShortNames; }
        public String[] getValues() { return this.Values; }
        public String[] getTypes() { return this.typesInInt; }
    }
}
```

First I added the two different lists without a binding by calling the Add() method of the list view, this worked but I couldnt work correctly with the list entries. For example I want to select some values and calculate an average value of them.
Then I tried to implement the MVVM-Pattern but I just cant bind the fields correctly so if the observableList entries receive an entry the view updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to bind each`TextBlock.Text` property to an entire `ObservableCollection` of strings.

```
<TextBlock Name="TextBlockName" Text="{Binding ShortNameStringObservableList}" />
```

That's never going to work.  `TextBlock.Text` wants a single string, not a collection of them.

If the list is going to show "machines" then create a class (a view-model) to represent each list entry *in its entirety*; to expose all the properties of one of a machine.   So don't create separate `ObservableCollection`s of individual elements of a machine.  Create one single `ObservableCollection` of this new view-model and bind the `ListBox` to *that*.

For example:

```
public class Machine
{
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Expose an observable collection of these

```
public ObservableCollection<Machine> Machines { get; }
```

Then bind the ListBox to it.  Use an ItemTemplate that shows whatever you need to see for one machine.

```
<ListBox Name="ListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Machines}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Machine}">
           <StackPanel>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShortName}" />
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
           </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: It worked, awesome! 
I added a ViewModel with two string fields and created an ObservableList of it. First I had forgotten to add getter and setter for the ObservableList but after adding them it worked fine.